# Group pages by custom field values

Tags: custom-field, templates, page-template

I plan to have each individual product as a page, with custom fields for : Brand, size, feature 1 and feature 2.

My question:

Will it be possible to build a summary page template say for Brand, based on the custom field?
I would like to be able to display a thumbnail for each brand, showing the count of products [ie pages] for each brand. When you click on the thumbnail I would like a second page listing each product with a link to the actual product page.

Is this a valid approach or is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

Custom fields are not intended as grouping mechanism, they are suited for data that can have wildly different values that are not group like. For example product *weight* would be a good candidate since it can wildly vary and typically there is no interest in grouping like "show me all products that weight 200g".

For information that has (relatively) narrow set of established values custom taxonomy are much better fit. In your case "Brand" would make a lot of sense as taxonomy rather than custom field. Since taxonomy are more logical for grouping they naturally come with support for taxonomy archives. See [`register_taxonomy()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy) documentation for details.